# Spring Integration JdbcMessageHandler - payload with multiple items

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jdbc

How can I process multiple messages in the payload?

I tried the following:

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outChannel")
 public MessageHandler jdbcMessageHandler() {
    JdbcMessageHandler jdbcMessageHandler = new JdbcMessageHandler(getDataSource(), getSql());

     jdbcMessageHandler.setPreparedStatementSetter((ps, message) -> {
            Item[] items = ((Item[]) message.getPayload());
            Arrays.stream(items).forEach(item -> {                
                    ps.setString(1, item.getName());
            }
            ps.addBatch();
    } 
    return jdbcMessageHandler;
}
```

But only last message inserted multiple times.
(Note: using java configuration and not xml for the beans)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jdbc.html#batch-update

> the `JdbcMessageHandler` performs a `JdbcOperations.batchUpdate()` if the payload of the request message is an `Iterable` instance.

`Iterable`, not an array as I see in your sample. So, consider to transform your array into a `List` and you should be good with handling a batch update for several items at once.

Comment: Hi Artem, Is there any way we can return the result of jdbc query from 'JdbcMessageHandler '

Comment: That’s a gateway functionality. The regular handler is one-way and about inserting or updating. The result set is something what you would like to produce . Therefore an outbound gateway. See JDBC support docs for more info.